# Is it bad practice to add a bunch of properties to request in Express or Connect?

Tags: node.js, express, connect

For example, say you use winston for logging, and instead of having each middleware to require the logger, you may have one (upstream) middleware that adds it to the `request` object, so that other middleware can just do:

```
request.logger.log(...)
```

Is this good or bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it's not really good practice to do so.

First of all, you clutter the `req` object with things you *hope* do not exist yet and will not exist in the future. If they do, you break things, perhaps even without noticing it. Even worse, when a property name you are using today is being used in a future version of *any* middleware you use, you have a problem. And for sure you do not check this every single time for every single minor update.

Then, it introduces dependencies between the middleware modules. But these dependencies are not explicit, they are implicit: It only works if middleware B is run after middleware A, but that's expressed nowhere in code. If you change the order, you may only end up with a little helpful `undefined is not a function` error.

These are my two main issues why I consider this a bad practice. Sure, there's no rule without exception, but if you ask for a rule of thumb, I'd try to avoid that.

By the way, when you take a look at the [Migrating Express 3.x to 4.x guide](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#connect-patches), you can read the following paragraph:

> Connect patched node's prototypes globally. This is considered bad behaviour and has been removed in Connect 3.

As this explicitly refers to the `res` object, this also perfectly answers that you should *not* do this, and that doing so should be considered bad practice.

This essentially says the same as I wrote here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks (and by the way that was a hard core edit ;) )

Comment: You're welcome :-). (And regarding the edit - I hope you don't mind?)

Comment: PS: If it helped and answered your question, it may be nice if you could mark my answer as *answer* :-)

Comment: (no the edit was OK!) As for the answer I tend to wait for at least a second answer before marking one as the one

Comment: Okay, I'm fine with that :-))